# Run a function on a WP page template - is_page_template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to run a function on a specific WP page template. The specific page is called `archive.php`.

**This is what I have so far in `functions.php`**

```
if ( is_page_template( 'bloginfo("stylesheet_directory")/archive.php' ) ) {
    function add_isotope() {
        wp_register_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'),  true );
        wp_register_script( 'isotope-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope-hideall.js', array('jquery', 'isotope'),  true );
        wp_enqueue_script('isotope-init');
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_isotope' );
} else {
    function add_isotope() {
        wp_register_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'),  true );
        wp_register_script( 'isotope-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.js', array('jquery', 'isotope'),  true );
        wp_enqueue_script('isotope-init');
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_isotope' );
}
```

The different between the functions is `isotope-hideall`, which hides all categories when the page is loaded. When not using `if`/`else` it hides all categories from all page templates when page is loaded, and that is not what I want. Therefor I am using `if`/`else` to locate the correct page template.

I have tried the following, but nothing seems to work:

`is_page_template( 'archive.php' )`

`is_page_template( 'get_template_directory_uri()'.'/archive.php' )`

Am I doing something wrong, or do you have a working solution for this?

Page can be found [here](http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/spectra-norge/fyrverkeri/).

Comment: Where is this code that you have given - as in what page / file is it in. You could look also at dequeue'ing the script run and then enque the required script on archive.php before get_header() is run. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style

Comment: The code I have given is located within the `functions.php`, sorry for not posting that.

Comment: Try is_page( 'archive' ) instead. is_page_template() will only return true for custom template files, which I assume this isn't. In your above code it will then always return false, and end up calling isotope-hideall.

Comment: Thank you. However, this did not work either... But I do see something different. - The Isotope is not being loaded at all.

Comment: You cannot have a **page** template called `archive.php`, that is a resevered template for date archives and custom post types. If that is the template you are trying to target, then you should use `is_archive()` or the specific tags like `is_date()`  or `is_post_type_archive()` for custom post type archives

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out. I have checked it out and it seems like it's not a page template. I just tried using `is_archive()`. Since I only have one archive, I guess there would be no reason writing `is_archive(archive.php)`? Right now it does not seems the correct function is beeing runned. But I see that I forgot to post a link to the page. Maybe you want to take a look.

Comment: `is_archive()` does not take any arguments, ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complete logic is wrong here. Archives are targeted with `is_archive()` or the more specific conditional tag `is_date()` for normal archives. Note that `is_archive()` returns true on category, author, tag, date and taxonomy pages, so `is_archive()` might be a bit too generic to use if you only need to target archive

Also, your conditionals should be inside the function, not outside it as the conditional checks are way too late for the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Your code should be something like this

```
function add_isotope() {
    if ( is_archive() ) { // Change as needed as I said
        // Enqueue scripts for archive pages
    } else {
        // Enqueue scripts for all other pages
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_isotope' );
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. The problem has been solved with help from you and @danjah. However, I am not sure what answer I should mark as accepted as both were much help.

Answer (score 2):

As Pieter Goosen points out, *archive.php* is reserved for built in WordPress-functionality. Rename your file to something else, for instance to *archives.php* and make sure you are naming your custom page template at det top of the file:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Archives */ ?>
```

Your code should then work with `is_page_template('archives.php')` as longs as its located on root in your template folder. If not add whatever folder structure you have in front of the filename, like so: `/folder/folder2/archives.php` .

To avoid repeating the function twice you should also consider solving this something like so:

```
 function add_isotope( $isotope ) {
    wp_register_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'),  true );
    wp_register_script( 'isotope-init', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/' . $isotope . '.js', array('jquery', 'isotope'),  true );
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope-init');
 }

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_isotope' );

 if ( is_page_template( 'archives.php' ) : 
    add_isotope( 'isotope-hideall' );
 else :
    add_isotope( 'isotope' );
 endif;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. The problem has been solved with help from you and @Pieter Goosen. However, I am not sure what answer I should mark as accepted as both were much help.

Comment: Good to hear. Go with the one from @Pieter Goosen. That's the cleanest one.

Comment: @Olen As both answers helped in solving the issue, you can always combine our answers into something that worked as an exact solution and then post that solution as an answer and accept that as the correct answer. ;-)